# Analyze big data with equal number of rows and column with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on some bunch of text tags and I have frequency of each tag appearing along with other. I am trying to read this data from one big csv file (20k x 20k) of `ints` with pandas and then trying to perform various operations on it (like few algebraic, filtering and searching). File is pretty small (just 700MB) but loading that much matrix in memory was taking too much time.

I am performing this analysis on my local computer which has **12 GB of RAM**.

I have already changed default `dtype` to `int16` and saved little bit of memory. I am aware of pandas chunk wise operation of reading csv by setting **chunksize** parameter. However, that works great when I have few columns and large rows. In my case, I have same number of rows and columns do I was not able to use it more efficiently. I can read entire file and load it in the DataFrame but it was very time consuming (every DataFrame operation was taking some 5-10 min).

When I am performing only algebraic operations, I can directly use numpy like following,

```
numpy.genfromtxt('file.csv', delimiter=',')
```

This was comparatively fast than loading it into pandas. However, this approach was failing when I am working on some similar file but now column contains some strings data (like some IDs, date etc). Is any way I can read such csv file and work with its data efficiently?

Comment: Can you post `df.memory_usage().sum()`?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem : `df.memory_usage().sum()` gave me 2995225328

Comment: Did you try passing `dtype` argument to `pd.read_csv` to see if it improves performance?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem, yes. I did. I couldn't see any significant improvement.

Comment: You could try reading to numpy first, then passing `data, columns, index` to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor.

Comment: Try using [Dask](https://dask.org/).  The API is similar to `pandas`